# Fragment not attached to context on Navigation Component

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-navigation

I was navigating through my fragment and suddenly this error happen

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment PesananFragment{3c77b29} (5987833e-384c-48a3-b41b-2d3d1ecad053)} not attached to a context.
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireContext(Fragment.java:805)
    at id.vividi.ui.utama.PesananFragment$fetchPaymentData$1.invokeSuspend(PesananFragment.kt:107)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:738)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
```

and this is my code causing this error

```
VolleySingleton.getInstance(requireContext()).addToRequestQueue(historyRequest)
```

This error always happened when I am navigating through this fragment
I've tried using **requireContext.applicationContext** nothing happen, the error still exists.

Comment: Where is that line being called from? Have you tried to put it in your fragments `onAttach` method?

Comment: i called it in ```onViewCreated``` method

Comment: So have you tried in the `onAttach` method? Or at least make sure all your logic is centered around onAttach much like in an activity its in onCreate

Comment: yes, but my app still crash and the error changing to recyclerview adapter

Comment: @DavidKroukamp did you mean i must migrating my logic to ```onAttach``` rather than in ```onViewCreated``` ?

Comment: Yes and where is your adapter code done? In onViewCreated? Post some more code so we can get an understanding of how it all hangs together

Comment: Yeah I'd suggest that, you can keep some code like findbyview etc but the actual business logic should be in onAttach as onAttach is called when the fragment is attached to an activity and thereafter is made visible

Comment: @DavidKroukamp here is my fragment https://pastebin.com/fuMbxfPB

Comment: You just use `rvPayment` i cant see it defined

Comment: im using kotlin synthetic, should i define it only for recyclerview ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your fragment is listening to some events and these are fired before the fragment is attached to context.

Try to use

```
private Context context;    

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.context= context;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    this.context= null;
}
```

and while using this context , add

```
if(context!=null)
```

Comment: im using this, but now my recyclerview adapter getting error ```rvPayment must not be null```

Comment: my recyclerview, here is my function https://pastebin.com/wF7E0DER

Comment: Declare rvPayment as nullable and access it like that rvPayment?